# json_encode gives HTML entities. How to convert convert matching XML conventions?

Tags: javascript, xml, json

I am starting to create a Samsung TV App, which runs a pretty tight system where I can barely work with more than JS and HTML5. Furthermore, I have to send a json request to my web server to get the data down to the emulator client. For easier representation of my data I wanted to covert the json into XML. But due to having utf-8 encoded data on the web, it seems impossible for me to automate the decoding from json and encoding into XML.

Not like in some of the posts and aritcles I read, the json_encode creates HTML entities except of representations as something like \uXXXXXX.

So, what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the json_encode creates HTML entities

No, it doesn't.

> except of representations as something like \uXXXXXX.

Those are JSON unicode escapes

> So, what can I do?

Parse the JSON as normal. Generate the XML as normal.

Any JSON library and any XML library should be able to handle unicode characters.

Comment: I tried that Google library for converting to XML. Didn't work. But anyway, I now use the normal array representation of the JSON object. Thank you.